# Warning: Function created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

im having a error im so frustrate right now. I think due to this error im also having another error of cannot reference other columns while adding a check constraint in the table. I have to use this function in check constraint to compare with end time.

```
  1  create or replace function timing(dat in date, bran in varchar2(30), audi in number)
  2  return number is time number
  3  begin
  4  select s_end into time from checking
  5  where s_date=dat and branch=bran and a_id = audi;
  6  return time;
  7* end timing
SQL> /
```

and my table is

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------
 S_ID                                      NOT NULL NUMBER
 M_ID                                               NUMBER
 A_ID                                               NUMBER
 S_DATE                                             DATE
 S_START                                            NUMBER
 S_END                                              NUMBER
 BRANCH                                             VARCHAR2(30)
```

The error is:

```
1/46 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting following: := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue. 
3/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character 
The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue. 
7/10 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
```

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Comment: 1/46     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting following:
         := . ) , @ % default character
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.                        3/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expectin
         the following:
         := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
         The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.               
7/10    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting      @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have posted this same question in a slightly different form. I'll answer here in slightly different form. A check constraint cannot reference a user defined function. Oracle does not permit it so your contention "have to use this function in check constraint" cannot be!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
create or replace function timing(dat in date, bran in varchar2, audi in number)
return number 
is 
time number;
begin
   select s_end into time 
   from checking
   where s_date=dat and branch=bran 
   and a_id = audi;
return time;
end :
/
```

Comment: alter table checking add constraint chk check(s_start>timing(s_date,branch,a_id))
                                                      
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "TIMING": invalid identifier